Migrate data from on-premise cluster to Azure Storage account file share
I have an app that's running inside an on-premise Kubernetes cluster. The app is being migrated into an Azure Kubernetes cluster. The app data needs to be migrated as well. The data is inside an NFS file share and needs to be transferred to an Azure storage account file share. The storage account is private, as well as the on premise cluster. The Azure network is connected with the on-premise cluster through an express route and there is a VM that routes the traffic from an IP address x.x.x.x to the corresponding private IP of the storage account inside its Azure VNET. So, the on-premise cluster can reach the file share only through x.x.x.x:445, that is the only clearance there is. I thought of the following approach:

Create a pod with a container on which both the Azure file share and the NFS CaaS one would be mounted.
Mount the Azure file share into the container inside the pod using "sudo mount".

There are two problems with this in my case:

Problem 1: The problem appears inside the second step. "sudo mount" requires root access. My on-premise cluster doesn't allow containers to run with the root user. "mount" requires root permissions. So running the "sudo mount" command directly in the shell of the container is probably not an option.

Problem 2: As far as I know, to reach the Azure storage account through a request, you have to use the hostname and not the IP address. I was not able to add it in the Dockerfile of the container I am running so I used "hostAliases" inside the deployment Kubernetes manifest for deploying this custom app into the on-premise container.
- ip: "x.x.x.x"
hostnames:
- "<filesharename>.file.core.windows.net"`



This actually worked.
Now, because problem 1 doesn't let me use the "sudo mount" command I tried using a persistent volume claim. In that case, when mounting the claim to the deployment of my pod, the host entry stops working. It gives the following error message:

Output: mount error: could not resolve address for eaktenonprodsa.file.core.windows.net: Unknown error

Without the volume mount, trying netcat inside the shell by reaching the 445 port through the set hostname inside "hostAliases" it works fine. I have a doubt that the hostAliases isn't yet applied to the pod by the time the claim tries to connect to the Azure file share and that it looks only into the node hosts entries. By the way, I don't have permissions to adapt node hosts entries.
Here is the Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Install necessary packages
# Install sudo in addition to netcat and cifs-utils
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    netcat \
    cifs-utils \
    sudo \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add a non-root user (optional but recommended)
RUN groupadd -g 1001 mygroup && \
    useradd -u 1001 -g mygroup -ms /bin/bash myuser && \
    usermod -aG sudo myuser

# Switch to the non-root user (optional)
USER myuser

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /home/myuser

# Command to run when the container starts
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

I can also provide other Kubernetes resources if needed.
f you have any advice it would be appreciated. Also, if you have any better approach on the whole migration process, please provide info.

For problem 1- Since containers cannot run with root privileges, and mount requires root access, you can use a PV and PVC to handle the mounting instead of directly using sudo mount within the container. For Problem 2 i.e. DNS Resolution for Azure File Share, when using PVC, k8s doesn’t apply hostAliases before mounting the volume. Instead of hostAliases, you can use NodeLocal DNS or CoreDNS to resolve the private IP address of your Azure File Share.

I don't have rights to edit DNS entries on the cluster level. So no real way to use CoreDNS from my side. Is there any other possible approach to my problem?

You can create a sidecar container that runs with elevated privileges and handles the mounting of the Azure file share on behalf of the main application container. The sidecar can handle the DNS resolution and mounting process, while your main app runs with normal non-root privileges.
